# FIFO implementation for PostgreSQL due to storage constraint

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I understand that PostgresSQL is MVCC as discussed in [this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/286143/best-practice-for-recycling-rows-on-postgresql-update-vs-insert-delete). I am running an app with this as the storage. But the data grows massive daily and the intention is to dump old data and replenish with new data. The purpose is both to meet storage constraint and to perform fast analytics.

Is there a FIFO implementation to dump the old data (in terms of their indices) when replenishing with new one, keeping storage size constant? Something like: if the index reaches a threshold, start dumping the first N indices, and pushing in the new N records (if a buffer is needed for this action, that is fine). My app is in Python and works with `psycopg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical solution for that is partitioning: add a new partition for each month or day and drop partitions that contain old data.

Comment: Thanks. I would probably go with this if a "reactive" FIFO solution doe not exist.